# Looking for spell check for java application which is using weblogic and angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, weblogic

Looking for spell check for java application which is using weblogic and angularjs, with out PHP. Please suggest on the same.

Thanks,
Shan

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use an editor called ATOM, in which you can set up some spell checker packages. Currently, we are using it.